# Чтение и поворот bmp

Tags: c++, bmp

Всем доброе время суток. 
Вопрос: как можно повернуть на заданный угол bmp изображение.
Инструментарий: стандартный библиотеки c++. Только консоль только хардкор.
А если подробнее, то открыть изображение, повернуть и сохранить. Умею поворачивать на 90 180 270 360 градусов и зеркалить, простой перестановкой пикселей местами.

Answer (score 2):

Смещаешь ось координат в точку поворота и вектор каждой точки умножаешь на матрицу поворота. f - угол в радианах.

[image: Формула]

Изза погрешности округления будут "дырки" так что их прийдется интерполировать